# Multiple titles in legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, legend

Is it possible to put multiple "titles" in a legend in matplotlib?
What I want is something like:

```
Title 1
x label 1
o label2

Title 2
^ label 3
v label 4

...
```

in case I have 4 curves or more. Because if I use more than 1 legend, it is difficult to get them aligned properly setting the positions manually.

Comment: I have done a similar problem in the past and I used these as reference

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo3.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo.html

hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the closest i got to it, was creating an empty proxy artist. Problem in my opinion
is that they are not left aligned but the space for the (empty) marker is still there.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

# the comma is to get just the first element of the list returned
plot1, = plt.plot(x, x**2) 
plot2, = plt.plot(x, x**3)

title_proxy = Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, color='w')

plt.legend([title_proxy, plot1, title_proxy, plot2], 
           ["$\textbf{title1}$", "label1","$\textbf{title2}$", "label2"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should correct your answer, it is `plot1, ` and `plot2, ` . But it works great! I will wait if anyone else can answer. Until now your answer is the closest one. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Ok so I needed this answered and the current answer didn't work for me. In my case I don't know beforehand how "often" I will need a title in the legend. It depends on some input variables so I needed something more flexible than manually setting where the titles would be. After visiting dozens of questions here I came to this solution that works perfectly for me, but maybe there was a better way of doing it.

```
## this is what changes sometimes for me depending on how the user decided to input
parameters=[2, 5]


## Titles of each section
title_2 = "\n$\\bf{Title \, parameter \, 2}$"
title_4 = "\n$\\bf{Title \, parameter \, 4}$"
title_5 = "\n$\\bf{Title \, parameter \, 5}$"



def reorderLegend(ax=None, order=None):
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    info = dict(zip(labels, handles))

    new_handles = [info[l] for l in order]
    return new_handles, order


#########
### Plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_axis_off()

## Order of labels
all_labels=[]
if 2 in parameters:
    ax.add_line(Line2D([], [], color="none", label=title_2)) 
    all_labels.append(title_2)
    #### Plot your stuff below header 2
    #### Append corresponding label to all_labels



if 4 in parameters:
    ax.add_line(Line2D([], [], color="none", label=title_4))
    all_labels.append(title_4)
    #### Plot your stuff below header 4
    #### Append corresponding label to all_labels

if 5 in parameters:
    ax.add_line(Line2D([], [], color="none", label=title_5))
    all_labels.append(title_5)
    #### Plot your stuff below header 5
    #### Append corresponding label to all_labels

## Make Legend in correct order
handles, labels = reorderLegend(ax=ax, order=all_labels)
leg = ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, fontsize=12, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), ncol=1, fancybox=True, framealpha=1, frameon=False)

## Move titles to the left 
for item, label in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.texts):
    if label._text  in [title_2, title_4, title_5]:
        width=item.get_window_extent(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).width
        label.set_ha('left')
        label.set_position((-2*width,0))
```

And as an example I get to the following legend (cropped out the rest of the image).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib only supports a single legend title, but I sometimes want multiple titles as well, and aligning the labels with the left edge of the legend box makes them look title-like when compared to the other labels with handles. I've found a few approaches to this:

## Move labels using Text.set_position()

This is similar to @M.O.'s answer. The tricky part is that `Text.set_position()` uses [display coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#), so we need to figure out exactly how many pixels to offset the label and can't just use fontsize units like we'd give to `plt.legend()`. By reading through  [`matplotlib.legend.Legend._init_legend_box()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.0/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L815) we can get a sense of what classes and parameters are involved. Matplotlib makes a tree of HPacker and VPacker objects:

```
VPacker
    Text (title, invisible if unused)
    HPacker (columns)
        VPacker (column)
            HPacker (row of (handle, label) pairs)
                DrawingArea
                    Artist (handle)
                TextArea
                    Text (label)
            ...
        ...
```

Legend kwargs/rcParams like `handletextpad`, `handlelength`, `columnspacing`, etc, are given to the HPacker, VPacker, and DrawingArea objects to control the spacing. The spacing params we're interested in are in "fontsize units", so if `handlelength=2`, then handles will be `2 * fontsize` points wide. And a "point" is an old typographic unit that equals 1/72 of an inch. By looking at the DPI of the figure we can convert points to pixels, but some matplotlib backends like SVG don't use pixels, so we want to use `Renderer.points_to_pixels()` instead of doing the calculation ourselves.

Going back to `_init_legend_box()`, it looks like labels get moved over by `handlelength + handletextpad`, but if we dig into HPacker, we see that it unconditionally adds a single pixel of padding around each of its children, so we need to add 2 more pixels: one for each side of the handle.

Finally, we need some way to mark legend entries as being titles, and setting `visible=False` on the handle seems good since handles must be an Artist (or subclass) instance, and every Artist has the `visible` property.

As code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

def style_legend_titles_by_setting_position(leg: mpl.legend.Legend, bold: bool = False) -> None:
    """ Style legend "titles"

    A legend entry can be marked as a title by setting visible=False. Titles
    get left-aligned and optionally bolded.
    """
    # matplotlib.offsetbox.HPacker unconditionally adds a pixel of padding
    # around each child.
    hpacker_padding = 2

    for handle, label in zip(leg.legendHandles, leg.texts):
        if not handle.get_visible():
            # See matplotlib.legend.Legend._init_legend_box()
            widths = [leg.handlelength, leg.handletextpad]
            offset_points = sum(leg._fontsize * w for w in widths)
            offset_pixels = leg.figure.canvas.get_renderer().points_to_pixels(offset_points) + hpacker_padding
            label.set_position((-offset_pixels, 0))
            if bold:
                label.set_fontweight('bold')
```

And in use:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_legend_with_subtitles() -> mpl.legend.Legend:
    legend_contents = [
        (Patch(visible=False), 'Colors'),
        (Patch(color='red'), 'red'),
        (Patch(color='blue'), 'blue'),

        (Patch(visible=False), ''),  # spacer

        (Patch(visible=False), 'Marks'),
        (plt.Line2D([], [], linestyle='', marker='.'), 'circle'),
        (plt.Line2D([], [], linestyle='', marker='*'), 'star'),
    ]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
    leg = fig.legend(*zip(*legend_contents))
    return leg

leg = make_legend_with_subtitles()
style_legend_titles_by_setting_position(leg)
leg.figure.savefig('set_position.png')
```

[image: multi-title legend using set_position]

## Modify legend contents and remove invisible handles

Another approach is to replace any legend entry HPackers that have invisible handles with just the label:

```
def style_legend_titles_by_removing_handles(leg: mpl.legend.Legend) -> None:
    for col in leg._legend_handle_box.get_children():
        row = col.get_children()
        new_children: list[plt.Artist] = []
        for hpacker in row:
            if not isinstance(hpacker, mpl.offsetbox.HPacker):
                new_children.append(hpacker)
                continue
            drawing_area, text_area = hpacker.get_children()
            handle_artists = drawing_area.get_children()
            if not all(a.get_visible() for a in handle_artists):
                new_children.append(text_area)
            else:
                new_children.append(hpacker)
        col._children = new_children

leg = make_legend_with_subtitles()
style_legend_titles_by_removing_handles(leg)
leg.figure.savefig('remove_handles.png')
```

[image: multi-title legend by removing handles]

Modifying the legend contents feels brittle, though. Seaborn has a function, [`adjust_legend_subtitles()`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12/seaborn/utils.py#L815-L832) that instead sets the DrawingArea width to 0, and if you also set `handletextpad=0` the labels almost get left-aligned, except that there's still the HPacker padding around the DrawingArea that keeps the label right 2 pixels.

## Make multiple legends and concatenate the contents together

[Seaborn's latest approach](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.12/seaborn/_core/plot.py#L1620-L1640) is to make multiple legend objects, using the `title` param for each, combining the contents into one primary legend, and then registering only that primary legend with the figure. I like this approach since it keeps matplotlib in control of styling the titles, and you could specify a cleaner interface to it than adding invisible handles, but I feel like it'd be more work to adapt to a non-seaborn context than using the other approaches.

Comment: could you please give an example for the last approach (combining all sub-legeneds into one primary legend)?